# How to set constraints to a tableView into a viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, constraints

I'm trying to place a tableView in a viewController, but im not able to constraint properly the tableView, i'm doing the usual things, i'm sticking the leading, trailing and bottom constraints to superview, and some space to the top superview. But as shown in the preview, table view does not look to be constrained, the effect that it brings for me is that when i put elements into content view, they extend along the right side i can not see them for small devices. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

[StoryBoard Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaHxT.png)

Comment: Maybe this can be only an stoyboard visual bug, can you try it? put some cells and run it on device or simulator must work as intended

Comment: Please take a photo.

Comment: Yes, after spending long time checking what happened i figured out that there is a Xcode fail on it, i run it in simulators and real devices and it works perfect, the bad thing is that everything i inserted into that view does not look as it should in the preview, but again, in simulator everything works fine. So,  preview is not always as trusty as i expected and now i know it. Thanks Reinier Melian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending long time checking what happened i figured out that there is a Xcode fail on it, i run it in simulators and real devices and it works perfect, the bad thing is that everything i inserted into that view does not look as it should in the preview, but again, in simulator everything works fine. So, preview is not always as trusty as i expected and now i know it

Comment: Yes, I got the same problem. Struggled a long time before I saw your post. Then ran it in the simulator, everything is lined up. In my case I was trying iPhone XR. In Storyboard, things in XR are not aligned even the constraints are same, but in XR simulator, they are good.